# How to create a user ID with google sign in

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-signin

I want add a user ID to my mysql database after a new user signs in using google auth. This documentation hints at what I should do, but I'm not sure of the details. So far, I've hacked together most of the steps, I think - but I'm learning as I go.

Everything's working, but I'm just not sure of next steps. So assuming a user doesn't exist in my DB, what, specifically do I use to create a new user ID?

This is the closest documentation I could find on what I want to do,but it's vague.

> If the user isn't yet in your user database, create a new user record
> from the information in the ID token payload, and establish a session
> for the user.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

**My frontend:**

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
   
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        var userName = profile.getName();
        var userEmail = profile.getEmail();
        var image = profile.getImageUrl();
            
        console.log('new user is:', userName,'the ID is',id_token, 'the email is: ', userEmail, 'and the picture is', image)


        // POST NEW USER TO BACK END;
        var postUrl = `http://localhost:80/newUser`
                // Send the data using post;
                try{
                    $.post(postUrl, {token: id_token, userName: userName, userEmail: userEmail, userProfilePicture: image })
                    .done(function (data) {
                        console.log('success sign up clause- data posted to backend')
                    });
                    console.log('hello')   
                }catch(err){     
                    console.log('failed to post to backend')
                    response.send('Error: ' + err)     
                }    

    }
```

**My backend:**

```
const CLIENT_ID = 'MyPresumablyPrivateInfo.apps.googleusercontent.com' const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library'); const client = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID);
       app.post('/newUser', async (request, response) => {
        console.log(request.body)
            var token = request.body.token
            var NewuserName = request.body.userName
            var NewuserEmail = request.body.userEmail

            //token = NewUserId
            // Check authenticity of user id
                const client = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID);

                    async function verify() {
                    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
                        idToken: token,
                        audience: CLIENT_ID,  
                    });
                    const payload = ticket.getPayload();
                    const userid = payload['sub'];
                    console.log('id verified!')
                    }
                verify().catch('error caught:', console.error);
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `sub` key in the token payload (email not recommended as it may change).

> An identifier for the user, unique among all Google accounts and never
> reused. A Google account can have multiple emails at different points
> in time, but the sub value is never changed. Use sub within your
> application as the unique-identifier key for the user.

[Source](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/google-auth-library/5.5.0/interfaces/TokenPayload.html)

Comment: Further support for this: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#create-an-account-or-session

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the user emails are unique so what I would do is hash the user's email
and use it as an id

I usually use [MD5 hashing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md5) as it can help you later in other stuff like using gavatar

Comment: I thought of this, but it seems like a kind of hacky approach, no?

Comment: why do you think that?

Comment: As I quoted in my question, the google docs specifically advise as follows: " create a new user record from the information in the ID token payload" - so perhaps calling your suggestion 'hacky' is unduly harsh, but it's not the strategy that google seem to advise, and given I'm such a novice and this stuff is important, I'd like to do it 'by the book'